# ASP.NET Display the progress bar/loading for radiobuttonlist & dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, loading-image

I am creating an ASP.NET/C# application. I want a **progress bar/loading** appear when selecting a `RadioButtonList` & `DropDownList`. The `RadioButtonList` & `DropDownList` is `AutoPostBack`.

I need to display a **progress bar/loading** for `RadioButtonList` & `DropDownList`.

Thank You.

```
function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some JavaScript and Html to show loader on each postback. 
Please find out the helping urls below:

[Display loading image while PostBack calls in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-loading-image-while-PostBack-calls-in-ASPNet.aspx)

[Locking the Screen During a Postback](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506152543/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121708-1.aspx)

[How to show loading image on every post back ?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1634121.aspx?How%20to%20show%20loading%20image%20on%20every%20post%20back%20)

[Show Loading Progress Indicator using GIF Image when UpdatePanel is updating in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Loading-Progress-Indicator-using-GIF-Image-when-UpdatePanel-is-updating-in-ASPNet.aspx)